# How to use before double click event multiple time in a one sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have following three codes for my suppose sheet X

- first code

  ```
  Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
  Dim rFound As Range, vFind
  If Target.Column = 3 Then

    Cancel = True
    vFind = Target
      On Error Resume Next

      With Sheet4.Columns(3)
          Set rFound = .Find(What:=vFind, After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
          LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
          :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
      End With
      On Error GoTo 0

      If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
          Application.Goto rFound
      Else
           MsgBox "No match for " & vFind & " on " & Sheet4.Name
         End If
  End If

  End Sub
  ```
- second code

  ```
   Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
       Dim rFound As Range, vFind
           If Target.Column = 2 Then

        Cancel = True
        vFind = Target
      On Error Resume Next

      With Sheet5.Columns(2)
          Set rFound = .Find(What:=vFind, After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
          LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
          :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
      End With
      On Error GoTo 0

      If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
          Application.Goto rFound
      Else
           MsgBox "No match for " & vFind & " on " & Sheet5.Name
          End If
          End If

          End Sub
  ```
- Third code

  ```
  Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
  Dim str As String
  Dim cboTemp As OLEObject
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = ActiveSheet

  Set cboTemp = ws.OLEObjects("ComboBox1")
  On Error Resume Next
  With cboTemp
  'clear and hide the combo box
   .ListFillRange = ""
   .LinkedCell = ""
   .Visible = False
    End With
   On Error GoTo errHandler
    If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
    'if the cell contains
      'a data validation list
     Cancel = True
     Application.EnableEvents = False
     'get the data validation formula
     str = Target.Validation.Formula1
     str = Right(str, Len(str) - 1)
     With cboTemp
     'show the combobox with the list
     .Visible = True
     .Left = Target.Left
     .Top = Target.Top
     .Width = Target.Width + 5
     .Height = Target.Height + 5
     .ListFillRange = str
     .LinkedCell = Target.Address
     End With
     cboTemp.Activate
     'open the drop down list automatically
      Me.ComboBox1.DropDown
   End If

  errHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub

  End Sub
  ```

Here I have three events for double click event in single sheet but as we know same macro name in one sheet is not allowed so can you guys please help me on this? I guess macro merge is only the option but well i am beginner in vba so I honestly don't know about this so, any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What if i have want to use two different macro for double click event in one sheet?

Comment: change 2nd 3 rd double click events to sub routine then call them from 1st double click.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't seem like it would be too hard to combine the disparate portions into a Select Case statement while preserving the like portions.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:C")) Is Nothing Then
        Cancel = True
        Dim rFound As Range, vFind As Variant

        'small bit of error control
        if isempty(target) then exit sub

        vFind = Target.value

        On Error Resume Next
        Select Case Target.Column
            Case 2
                With Sheet5.Columns(2)
                    Set rFound = .Find(What:=vFind, After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                                       LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                End With
            Case 3
                With Sheet4.Columns(3)
                    Set rFound = .Find(What:=vFind, After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                                       LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                End With                
        End Select
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            Application.Goto rFound
        Else
            MsgBox "No match for " & vFind & " on " & _
                   iif(target.column = 3, Sheet4.Name, Sheet5.Name)
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You have merged macro. Great, and thank you so much for allocating your valuable time and solving issue.